# Divide in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I try to show from my 16 machines the highest machine which produced the most waste. And after a lot of efforts I´ve done this.

Now I must do the top 5 of highest problems. And these Problems are listed in the database in the same directory´:

How can I do this?

I use SQL Server Report Builder.

I cannot add a picture I will try to do it so:

```
Date                        CounterName                  calculationUnitsInitial     
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Prod                     6221   
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Bad                          0  
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 ba           0  
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 ba       0  
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Ausg     6    
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Au           0  
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Bad                          125    
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Aus                          8  
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Band position                0  
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Fe               0  
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Fe               0
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Hu                       124    
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 S                     0 
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 Dr               0
    2016-04-26 00:00:00.000 H            4
```

Comment: Could you give us the table structures that you're working with, we'll then be able to help a lot better.

Comment: yes sure I will do it .

Comment: I edited my question now

Comment: We actually prefer text over pictures - we can't copy & paste a picture into our own editors if we want to recreate your data locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we need a list of the problems in descending order of frequency for the worst operating machine. I'd set up your really big query as a dataset and use that to populate the default value of a hidden parameter called `Machine`. We will also need two parameters `DateFrom` and `DateTo` with their default values set to the date range you are interested in.

Then your problem selection is easy:

```
SELECT CounterName, COUNT(*) AS Problems
FROM Problems
WHERE Machine = @Machine 
  AND ProblemDate >= @DateFrom AND ProblemDate <= @DateTo
GROUP BY CounterName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Now we have a nice list of the number of each type of problem for that machine in descending order of occurrence of problems. Let's call this dataset `Problems`

Add a table to your report with two columns. The first column will have the expression:

```
=Fields!Problems.Value / SUM(Fields!Problems.Value, "Problems")
```

This divides the number of problems for that CounterName by the entire number of problems in the dataset Problems. Set the Format property of that cell to `P1` to display as a percentage with one decimal place.

The second column is simply the field `CounterName`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it